# sending date time stamps to elasticsearch through python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, elasticsearch

I have 3 of 5 columns of my data that is in pandas to_datetime format:

```
col1                 col2                col3                col4            a           
2017-01-01 21:07:57  2017-01-01 21:07:58 2017-01-01 21:07:59 misc_text_data  text
2017-01-01 21:07:42  2017-01-01 21:07:48 2017-01-01 21:07:49 misc_test_data  text2
2017-01-01 21:07:33  2017-01-01 21:07:22 2017-01-01 21:07:21 mist_test_fata  fext3
```

How can I send my data to elasticsearch via the elasticsearch.py field?

I am trying to get elasticsearch to recognize the format as timedate stamps so I can do timeline analysis from these dates.

I am currently sending my data like below with no recognition of the times:

```
mylist = []
for doc in df_json:
    doc['tag'] = "mytags"
    action = { "_index":"myindexoftimes", "_type": "mytimes", "_source":doc}
    mylist.append(action)

helpers.bulk(es, mylist)
```

Any assistance would be helpful. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what is the problem in your code, it is probably to do with the timestamp format.

Anyway panda to_json with iso format selected worked for me:

```
import pandas as pd
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import json

es = Elasticsearch()

data = ["2017-01-01 21:07:57,  2017-01-01 21:07:58, 2017-01-01    21:07:59, misc_text_data,  text".split(','),
    "2017-01-01 21:07:42,  2017-01-01 21:07:48, 2017-01-01 21 07:49, misc_test_data,  text2".split(','),
    "2017-01-01 21:07:33,  2017-01-01 21:07:22, 2017-01-01 21 07:21, misc_test_fata,  fext3".split(',')]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns = ['col1','col2','col3','col4','a'])
for col in ['col1','col2','col3']:
df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col])

jsons = json.loads(df.to_json(orient='records',date_format='iso'))

for j in jsons:
    j['injection_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime('now')
    es.index(index="test33", doc_type='time_text', body=j)
```